# locationOfTouch results in SIGABRT

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to figure out why I get an error when I use locationOfTouch:inView. Eventually I created a new view with just the locationOfTouch call and I still get a SIGABRT whenever I touch the view.

Aside from import statements, here's all the code in my view:

```c
@interface Dummy : UIView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *repositionRecognizer;
}

@end
```

Here's the impl:

```c
@implementation Dummy

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        repositionRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                 initWithTarget:self 
                         action:@selector(reposition:)];
        [repositionRecognizer setDelegate:self];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:repositionRecognizer];

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)reposition:(UIGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer {
    [gestureRecognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self];
    //[gestureRecognizer locationInView:self];
}

@end
```

If I use locationInView, it works okay.  If I use locationOfTouch:inView, the program aborts as soon as the touch ends.

EDIT: On the console, with this class, no error messages are shown.  The IDE points to main.m with a SIGABRT.  Clicking on 'Continue' results in 'EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION'.  Screenshot available on http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/consolel.png/

Comment: Please post the console error message.

Comment: The console is blank.  See here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/consolel.png/

Comment: In your console gdb> do a backtrace or bt to see last stack that crashed. Set environment variable NSZombieEnabled to YES and debug your code.

Comment: Thanks, @0x8badf00d, but it wasn't much help:
`(gdb) bt`
`#0  0x95040c5a in __kill ()`
`#1  0x95040c4c in kill$UNIX2003 ()`
`#2  0x950d35a5 in raise ()`
`#3  0x950e96e4 in abort ()`
`#4  0x95065b1b in _Unwind_Resume ()`
`#5  0x012fae39 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()`
`#6  0x012faccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()`
`#7  0x012ad879 in GSEventRunModal ()`
`#8  0x012ad93e in GSEventRun ()`
`#9  0x0001ba9b in UIApplicationMain ()`
`#10 0x00002968 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffece4) at /Users/me/projects/dir/dir/project/AngledRectPOC/main.m:9`
`#11 0x000028c5 in start ()`

Comment: Could you please show us how you init this Dummy view?

Comment: @tia
    `Dummy  *dv = [[Dummy alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 800, 500, 200)];`
    `[self.view addSubview:dv];`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This crashes because it assumes that there is a touch zero. You need to confirm there is one first, like so:

```
- (void)reposition:(UIGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer.numberOfTouches > 0){
        CGPoint point = [gestureRecognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self];
        NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
    }
}
```

Think of the "`locationOfTouch:`" part as saying "`touchAtIndex:`", if the array of touches is empty(When you lift your finger or move it off the screen) then there is no `touchAtIndex:0`.